# How can I write a special website response as a dictionary to CSV file?

Tags: python, json, csv

From an API I've got a JSON response as a dictionary type. I would like to write the content in a CSV file, but I fail.

Here is the API response (shortened,anoymized):

```
{'total': 99, 'list': [{'id': 'xxxxxxxx', 'name': 'foobar x', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 1234.5}, {'id': 'yyyyyyyy', 'name': 'foobar y', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 2345.6}, {'id': 'zzzzzzzz', 'name': 'foobar z', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 3456.7}]}
```

I've tried many variants, but I fail. I do not want the key/value 'total' and from 'list' only the items in it.

All examples does not have `{'total': 99, 'list':` part.

Here is the last try (shortened):

```
import csv

my_payload = client.request('GET', 'Opportunity')

field_names = ['id','name','deleted','amount']

print(type(my_payload))

with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = field_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in my_payload:
        writer.writerow(my_payload[1])

exit()
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/bin/espo_get_opportunities.py", line 33, in <module>
    writer.writerow(my_payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'list', 'total
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response always has a `'list'` field in the top-level dictionary then you can loop over `my_payload["list"]` instead of just `mypayload`. The loop variable `data` will contain each list item in turn, and each item is itself a dictionary with keys `id`, `name` etc. Therefore you can write `data` direct to the csv in the loop.

Code:

```
import csv

my_payload = {'total': 99, 'list': [{'id': 'xxxxxxxx', 'name': 'foobar x', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 1234.5}, {'id': 'yyyyyyyy', 'name': 'foobar y', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 2345.6}, {'id': 'zzzzzzzz', 'name': 'foobar z', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 3456.7}]}

field_names = ['id','name','deleted','amount']

print(type(my_payload))

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = field_names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in my_payload['list']:
        print('row: ', data)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Note that I left a debugging print statement in the loop to illustrate what is happening, for the real code you should remove that.

Program output:

```
<class 'dict'>
row: {'id': 'xxxxxxxx', 'name': 'foobar x', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 1234.5}
row: {'id': 'yyyyyyyy', 'name': 'foobar y', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 2345.6}
row: {'id': 'zzzzzzzz', 'name': 'foobar z', 'deleted': False, 'amount': 3456.7}
```

Contents of csv file:

```
id,name,deleted,amount
xxxxxxxx,foobar x,False,1234.5
yyyyyyyy,foobar y,False,2345.6
zzzzzzzz,foobar z,False,3456.7
```

---

However, I suspect that the actual response you get from the API is structured slightly differently than the dictionary that you showed, given the error message that you get and the use of `my_payload[1]`. However, I think you will be able to use the general principle as outlined above, probably in the form of `for data in my_payload[1]['list']` or something similar.

Comment: You made my day! It was so simple, but sometimes you don't see the problem. Thx!